# A certain parameter has 3 possible values, and there are n such parameters with 3 values each. Need to create scenarios by randomly changing them

Tags: c, matlab

A certain parameter has ***3*** possible values, and there are ***n*** such parameters with 3 values each. Need to create scenarios by randomly changing them and save each scenario as a text file, without any duplicated scenarios.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Count from 0 to 3<sup>n</sup>-1, and convert your number to an n-digit base-3 number (including leading zeros). Each digit in the result represents the value for one parameter.

Comment: Nice (+1). For the conversion, dec2base can be used: http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/dec2base.html