# Create a number with several digit in C++

Tags: c++, numbers, digits

I have 3 digits (1,4,6) and I want to create a number with 2 digits from my digits like 11,14,16,41,44,46,61,64,66.

What command should I use in c++ ?

Comment: You will most probably need to write some code to generate this output. What have you tried so far, can you provide a code sample.

Comment: Note that without your code you will likely not get any help.  ***Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. If we can't see enough work on your part your question will likely be booed off the stage; it will be voted down and closed.*** https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11499807/179910).

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking for homework help **must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it**.*

Answer (score 2):

There is no single command for this.  You have to write the code yourself, eg:

```cpp
int arr[] = {1, 4, 6};
for(int a : arr) {
    for(int b : arr) {
        cout << a << b << endl;
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/VacF8z)

Alternatively:

```cpp
int arr[] = {1, 4, 6};
for(int a : arr) {
    for(int b : arr) {
        int value = (a * 10) + b;
        cout << value << endl;
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/oQ0SJw)

Comment: Or even: `for (int a : arr) {for (int b : arr) {/*...*/}}`.

Comment: @Jarod42 indeed, I updated my answer. I often forget about things like that, since I still use a C++98 compiler at my day job.